# Erro ao instalar gulp-imagemin via NPM

Tags: npm, gulp

Estou tentando instalar o gulp-imagemin para otimização de imagens via NPM mas está ocorrendo erros.

Quando rodo o seguinte comando no terminal, erros de permissão retornam.

```
sudo npm install gulp-imagemin --save-dev
```

Erros:

```
gifsicle@4.0.1 postinstall /home/bruno/workspace/gds-wp2/node_modules/gifsicle
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ gifsicle pre-build test passed successfully

> jpegtran-bin@4.0.0 postinstall /home/bruno/workspace/gds-wp2/node_modules/jpegtran-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ⚠ EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/bruno/workspace/gds-wp2/node_modules/jpegtran-bin/vendor'
  ⚠ jpegtran pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✖ Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/bruno/workspace/gds-wp2/node_modules/jpegtran-bin/300d0d91-da15-4485-99b7-54a17a906294'

> optipng-bin@5.1.0 postinstall /home/bruno/workspace/gds-wp2/node_modules/optipng-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ⚠ EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/bruno/workspace/gds-wp2/node_modules/optipng-bin/vendor'
  ⚠ optipng pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✖ Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/bruno/workspace/gds-wp2/node_modules/optipng-bin/14ef0873-de46-43a9-bd55-a944ce91d156'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ gulp-imagemin@5.0.3
added 243 packages from 150 contributors and audited 11368 packages in 125.035s
found 10 vulnerabilities (5 low, 2 moderate, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

E então, quando tento rodar o `gulp img` no terminal para a otimização das imagens, o gulp retorna o seguinte erro:

```
[16:46:07] Using gulpfile ~/workspace/gds-wp2/gulpfile.js
[16:46:07] Starting 'img'...
[16:46:07] 'img' errored after 304 ms
[16:46:07] Error in plugin "gulp-imagemin"
Message:
    spawn /home/bruno/workspace/gds-wp2/node_modules/optipng-bin/vendor/optipng ENOENT
Details:
    errno: ENOENT
    code: ENOENT
    syscall: spawn /home/bruno/workspace/gds-wp2/node_modules/optipng-bin/vendor/optipng
    path: /home/bruno/workspace/gds-wp2/node_modules/optipng-bin/vendor/optipng
    spawnargs: -strip,all,-clobber,-fix,-o,3,-out,/tmp/803070bf-7ad3-4981-a2a7-4d6550a09b6f,/tmp/6e4684d9-75a5-4557-80a1-1867e6884065
    killed: false
    stdout: 
    stderr: 
    failed: true
    signal: null
    cmd: /home/bruno/workspace/gds-wp2/node_modules/optipng-bin/vendor/optipng -strip all -clobber -fix -o 3 -out /tmp/803070bf-7ad3-4981-a2a7-4d6550a09b6f /tmp/6e4684d9-75a5-4557-80a1-1867e6884065
    timedOut: false
    fileName: /home/bruno/workspace/gds-wp2/assets/images/Captura de tela de 2018-10-09 15-54-21.png
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false
```

Creio que seja pela falta dos diretorios da qual foi dado erro de permissão. Tentei cria-los manualmente e nada adiantou.

Tentei reinstalar o node, nada também.

Tentei voltar para a versão 3.4.0 do imagemmin, pediu os pacotes gifsicle, jpegtran-bin, optipng-bin, quando os três pacotes instalados o mesmo erro acontece.

Versão npm: 6.9.0

Versão Gulp:

CLI version: 2.2.0

Local version: 4.0.0